# Simple set theory problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

List all the elements of the set:
$\{1/n \mid n ∈ \{3, 4, 5, 6\}\}$

My understanding is that, first we must understand what n is. n is a set of its own, and its elements also are inside of {3, 4, 5, 6}. With this information, I believe I only know what n **could** be, but not exactly what it is. Once I figure out what n exactly is, I can plug each element of n into 1/n to solve for the resulting set. Am I on the right track? Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are just 4 elements 1/3 .. 1/6.  I think you are overly complicating things

Comment: $n$ is not a set. Are you confusing $\in$ with $\subset$?

Comment: @columbus8myhw Technically, every object in set theory is a set, but in this case it is besides the point.

Comment: I initially thought of n as a set. You are right, I had confused ∈ with ⊂.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a similar example.  The set $\{n^2~|~n\in\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ is read as "The set of all numbers such that the number is of the form $n^2$ for some value of $n$ where $n$ is any of $1,2,3,4$."

In my example, $n$ could have been equal to $1$, or it could have been equal to $2$, etc... in which case the numbers $1,4,9,16$ all fit the description (since $1=1^2, 4=2^2, 9=3^2, 16=4^2$), so $\{n^2~|~n\in\{1,2,3,4\}\}=\{1,4,9,16\}$.

In an attempt to explain it a different way, you can take each possibility for $n$ and "plug it in" to the expression.  Each result that you get like this will be in the final set.

---

With your example, $\{\frac{1}{n}~|~n\in\{3,4,5,6\}\}$, by "plugging in" each possible value of $n$, you get four answers.  These answers will be the elements of the set.

> the answers being $\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{6}$

---

Be warned that this idea of "plugging in" and making a list of results doesn't work very well if the number of possibilities for $n$ are large or even perhaps infinitely large.  Take for example $\{n^2~|~n\in\mathbb{N}\} = \{0,1,4,9,16,25,36,\dots\} = \{\text{the set of all perfect squares}\}$, so it may require a bit more thought in how to approach in a general fashion.